# What can I learn from $\alpha a_{n+1}<a_{n}<\beta a_{n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I had an HW question - given a series $a_{n}$ with $a_{1}=1$ and the relation $$2a_{n+1}<a_{n}<3a_{n+1}$$ to prove that the sequence is bounded and convergent. I got intuition for that question by finding a sequence that satisfies the assumptions, and I wanted to generalize it. So for $$\alpha a_{n+1}<a_{n}<\beta a_{n+1}$$ with $\alpha<\beta, a_{1}=1$, I proved that the sequence $$a_{n}=\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2\alpha\beta}\right)^{n}$$ is valid, but I got to it from intuition and trying several formulas. Now I want to check whether this is the only sequence satisfying those conditions, or if I can define $$a_{n}=\frac{f\left(\alpha,\beta,n\right)}{g\left(\alpha,\beta,n\right)}$$ and find some constraints on $f,g$, or a relation between them (aside that $f<g$ for $n>1$). Any ideas on how can I approach this?

I can prove that the series converges to zero, but is this the only thing to learn on a series like this?

Comment: There are plenty of such sequences! You can construct them step by step, choosing *any* $a_{n+1}$ in the interval $(a_n/\beta,a_n/\alpha).$

Comment: In fact, for $\alpha,\beta>0$, the statement $\alpha a_{n+1}<a_n<\beta a_{n+1}$ is equivalent to $\frac{1}{\beta}a_n<a_{n+1}<\frac{1}{\alpha}a_n$. Now you can use, e.g. induction to prove $\frac{1}{\beta^n}a_0<a_n<\frac{1}{\alpha^n}a_0$ etc. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $\alpha > 1$ you get that $a_{n+1} < a_n$ which indicates the function is *strictly* decreasing. With any $\beta > \alpha > 1$ and $a_0 \ge 0$ it gives $a_{n+1} > \frac{a_n}{\beta}$. Notice that if $a_n$ is positive (resp. negative), then $a_{n+1}$ is also positive (negative). You can prove by reccurence then that $a_0 > 0$ implies $a_n > 0$, ie the sequence $(a_i)_i$ is strictly decreasing, bounded by 0, thus converging (and bounded by both $a_0$ and 0).